# How to data bind DataGrid and 2D array

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, 2-way-object-databinding

I need to model a property in my model which has a 2D structure of `float`. I plan to represent it as a 2D array (`double[,]`).

The point is that I want to use a DataGrid (native of WPF) for two-way data binding to the array.

My intended result is something similar to a spreadsheet: if I edit a cell, the corresponding value in the array should change.

My doubts are:

1. Usually, each `DataGridRow` represents a typed item in a collection, while each column of this row represents a property of this item. Instead of this, I would need to represent each cell by index, and the number of columns would depend on the array width;
2. Each cell should be bound to a given array position, by index. How should this binding be declared? Should only `ItemsSource={Binding SomeArrayThing}` be enough?

Comment: Can you give me picture how it should look like?

Comment: @Ganesh It would be the same appearence of an Excel spreadsheet: a grid filled with values, labeled rows and columns.

Comment: If it is 2D array, are you trying to fill two columns and N-number of rows?

Comment: @Ganesh not quite. It is 2-dimensional in the sense that I have N columns x M rows. In my specific case, there are 15 rows and 8 columns.